# Proof that a continously differentiable, stable map is has an everywhere-invertible derivative matrix

Tags: real-analysis

I apologize for the lack of TeX, I'm new to stack exchange.
I am trying to solve the problem:
Let U be an open subset of R" and suppose that the continuously differentiable mapping F: U ->- R^n is stable. Prove that at each point χ in U, the derivative matrix DF(x) is invertible. 
(Hint: Use the First-Order Approximation Theorem.)

By stable, this text (Fitzpatrick), means that for x,y in U, there exists c >0 st. ||F(x)- F(y|| > c||x-y||.

The first-order approx. theory gives us that at any point x in U,  0 = lim h->0 ||F(x+h)-F(x) -DF(x)h|| / ||h||. ||F(x+h)-F(x) -DF(x)h|| / ||h|| > (||F(x+h) - F(x)|| - ||DF(x)h||)/ ||h|| by triangle inequality > c - ||DF(x)h||/||h|| by the stability property.

So, lim h-> 0 ||DF(x)h||/||h|| = c >0.

But that's where I get stuck.... how does that last property imply that DF(x) is invertible?

Comment: Nevermind, I solved this myself, after reviewing a little linear algebra.

Answer (score 0):

For $\mathbf u\in\mathbb R^n$, take $\mathbf h\in\mathbb R^n$ such that 
$
\mathbf h=\dfrac{r\mathbf u}{2\|\mathbf u\|}
$. Then it is easy to note
$$ \|\mathbf{D F}(\mathbf{x}) \mathbf{u}\|\geq \frac{c}{2}\|\mathbf u\|
$$
It follows that 
 $$\|\mathbf{D F}(\mathbf{x}) \mathbf{h}\|\geq \frac{c}{2}\|\mathbf h\|, \qquad \text{for all } h\in\mathbb R^n$$
 Therefore, $\mathbf{D F}(\mathbf{x})$ is invertible.